# Update django foreign key field

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have a foreign key field called books (in the model Book) in an intermediate model called Link_Book_Courses.

I'd like to add multiple Book objects to this. How do I do that in django?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Related Objects have an add() method:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add

You can add several like this

```
mymodel.related.add(*OtherModel.objects.filter(...))
```

Answer (score 1):

For one [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) you can only have one book. So to add multiple entries, you’ll have to add multiple `Link_Book_Courses`-objects. However what you might really want is a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).